# How to have different view based on date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem in having a different view by comparing today's date and expired date. Before I'm telling deeper about my problem, let me show you the code:

**buyer table**

```
id
name
address
phone_no
email
expired_at (date)
created_at
```

**BuyerController.php**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
   $buyers = Buyer::create([
       'name' => $request->name,
       'address' => $request->address,
       'phone_no' => $request->phone_no,
       'email' => $request->email,
       'expired_at' => Carbon::today()->addDays(730),
   ]);

   return response()->json($buyers);
}
```

**buyers\index.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-hover" id="buyer-table">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Address</th>
               <th>Phone No</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Registered Date</th>
               <th>Liability Period</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       @foreach($buyers as $buyer)
          <tr class="buyer{{$buyer->id}}">
              <td>{{$buyer->buyer_id}}</td>
              <td>{{$buyer->name}}</td>
              <td>{{$buyer->address}}</td>
              <td>{{$buyer->phone_no}}</td>
              <td>{{$buyer->email}}</td>
              <td>{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($buyer->created_at))}}</td>
              @if(now() < $buyer->expired_at)
                 <td class="text-success">Valid</td>
              @else
                 <td class="text-danger">Expired</td>
              @endif
          </tr>
        @endforeach
   </table>
</div>
```

Until here, I manage to complete my code which I successfully compared the expired date and today's date in the table view.

**web.php**

```
 Route::get('/report-form','ComplaintController@create');
```

**ComplaintController.php**

```
public function create()
{
   return view('buyers.complaints.create');
}
```

However, before deciding to develop this new idea, buyer can just view the create.blade.php in order to make a new complaint. But now, if the `expired_at` is already passed today's date, buyer can not make any complaint which will return to view expired.blade.php.

**buyers\complaints\create.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Make New Report</strong></h3>
</div>

//There is a form for the buyers to fill in the complaint
```

**buyers\complaints\expired.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Sorry you can't make any report</strong></h3>
</div>
```

I only have an idea to make if else statement in function create() but I do not know what is the correct query. What I already tried:

```
public function create()
  {
     $expired = Buyer::select('id')->where('expired_at','>', now())->get();
     $valid = Buyer::select('id')->where('expired_at','<', now())->get();
     if ($expired) {
         return view('buyers.complaints.create');
     }
     elseif ($valid) {
         return view('buyers.complaints.expired');
     }
  }
```

I do not know what I'm trying to do because there is no difference. If the buyers liability period has end (expired date has passed today's date) also can view the **buyers\complaints\create.blade.php** and I'm still new in Laravel. So, I hope there is someone can help me in figuring this out. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `get` returns a Collection (which is an object) ... when you are evaluating an object as a boolean, they are **ALWAYS** `true` in php .... `if ($expired)` is always true

Comment: @lagbox so what I need to do?

Comment: are you just looking for the existence of any Buyer with an expired_at > now? or a particular Buyer or any other criteria?

Comment: I’m checking on Buyer’s expired_at > now. If Buyer’s expired_at > now it will go to create.blade to make a complaint. if Buyer’s expired_at < now it will go to expired.blade. Is this answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

You only have 2 outcomes (unless a blank response was a 3rd) so one query to check the existence of a record should work:

```
if (Buyer::where('expired_at', '>=', now())->exists()) {
    return view('buyers.complaints.create');
}

return view('buyers.complaints.expired');
```

This is assuming you are looking for any Buyer who still isn't expired.

If you want to restrict this to a certain buyer and pass the buyer to the view:

```
$buyer = Buyer::findOrFail($buyerId);

$view = ($buyer->expired_at >= now()) ? 'create' : 'expired';

return view('buyers.complaints.'. $view, ['buyer' => $buyer]);
```

Comment: I already try your code but it seems like the system is ignoring the else statement which `return view('buyers.complaints.expired');` if `expired_at < now()`. Does this have to do with buyer's id?

Comment: you are not checking for any particular 'id' ... this is just looking for any buyer who isn't expired, as per the code you had and your answers to the comments ... what other criteria would you like to add to the query to filter it down?